# KeyError while trying to access list item by string reference in python

Tags: python-3.x

```
animals = [
    {
            "bird": ["crow"]
    },
    {
            "fish": ["salmon", "anchovy", "monkfish"]
    }
]
def getBirdsArray():
    birds = []
    fishes = []
    for animal in animals:
        for r in animal["bird"]:
            birds.append(r)
            print("birds are", birds)

        for r in animal["fish"]:
            fishes.append(r)
            print("fishes are", fishes)
```

Expected : birds are ["crow"]
fishes are ["salmon", "anchovy", "monkfish"]

Actual result:

```
  for r in animal["fish"]:
KeyError: 'fish'
```

Using `get("fish")` did not help.

I do not want to do animals[0 or animals[1] but I want flexibility to find item by searching through string index rather than using numeric index. I was using array as wrapper as array holds multiple keys which is a pattern.

In future this structure will become which is just indication that it will be more and more nested so I have to be careful on approach I use now.

```
animals = [
{
   "birds":[
      "id":23,
      "color":"blue",
      "owner":[
         {
            "id":23
         },
         {
            "ownerName":"Harold"
         }
      ]
   ]
},
{
   "fish":[
      "salmon",
      "anchovy",
      "monkfish"
   ]
}
  ]
```

Comment: right because rule 1 has no key "fish" and rule 2 has no key "bird".  You could catch the KeyError or check the existence of the key you're looking for. (Catching the error is more Pythonic)

Comment: But, I am only referencing to whatever I wanted to iterate through right ? Why should it have problem ? first statement iterates only to bird and second to fish only. I thought it only picks what item is selected in wrapping for loop.

Comment: I need to use fish and bird in different contexts. Directly referencing was not good approach I suppose. I hate duplicating code as well just as you suggested but trust me it created more problem. This was cleaner approach ? Also, index of animals could change anytime. I do not want to depend on animals[0] or animals[1] insteag get value exactly and iterate through.

Answer (score 2):

The problem isn't in the `for` loop. The problem is in the expression `animal["bird"]` and `animal["fish"]`.

Consider the first time the loop executes. In this case,

```
animal = {"bird": ["crow"]}
```

You'll note that the key "fish" is entirely absent. So what happens when you do `animal["fish"]` inside the `for` loop? You get a `KeyError`! The same thing would happen for the second iteration, where the key "bird" is entirely absent.

---

`dict.get()` is resistant to this problem*, if you provide it a default value to return in case the key is not found (in this case, an empty list should cause the interior of the `for` loop to be skipped without causing an error). This modification should fix your code to work as intended:

```
for animal in animals:
        for r in animal.get("bird", []):
            birds.append(r)
            print("birds are", birds)

        for r in animal.get("fish", []):
            fishes.append(r)
            print("fishes are", fishes)
```

---

*`dict.get()` is essentially equivalent to either of the following two functions:

```
def get(self, key, default=None):
    try:
        return self[key]
    except KeyError:
        return default

def get(self, key, default=None):
    if key in self:
        return self[key]
    else:
        return default
```

it's a little more complicated than that, because it always is, but it saves the step of having to put an entire try/except block.

Comment: Oh okay, looks like i missed to pass [] as default error handling in loop I suppose. Let me try this.

Comment: Do you think as other comment suggested this implementatioon could have been wrapped inside by {} than [] which in other words object than array. I will have more items added in future into this. I like array than object.

Comment: And, yes we should try to avoid lot of code when we can. Using get() might be better than try-catch. Not sure if there is any problem in using get() for avoiding any runtime issues.

Comment: @surendrapanday The performance difference between `[]`, `{}`, `(,)` will be negligible for this use case.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want something more like this, where it's a dictionary with animal entries.  Avoid unnecessary nesting in it, that just complicates things.  Test for which entry you're on, then loop though those, to append your new birds and fishes containers.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

animals = {
    "bird": ["crow"],
    "fish": ["salmon", "anchovy", "monkfish"]
}

def getAnimals():
    birds = []
    fishes = []
    for rule in animals:
        if rule == "bird":
            for r in animals[ rule ]:
                birds .append( r )
            print( "birds are", birds )

        if rule == "fish":
            for r in animals[ rule ]:
                fishes .append( r )
            print( "fishes are", fishes )

getAnimals()
```

> birds are ['crow']
> fishes are ['salmon', 'anchovy', 'monkfish']

Comment: I thought using array to wrap multiple objects is a pattern to follow rather than making an object. But, either way at least it may fix problem.

Comment: I could only see that as a benefit if you have **thousands** of entries.  A list of many smaller dicts *might* be quicker to iterate then one large dict.  Is that something you were looking to do?

Comment: The array I have given above is likely to get quite complex with lots of data so also existing code uses list which is changed to set() before code is run. Data is not in thousands but maybe 20 items inside with lot of nested values and values inside values inside values.

Answer (score 0):

```py
animals = [
    {
            "bird": ["crow"]
    },
    {
            "fish": ["salmon", "anchovy", "monkfish"]
    }
]
def getBirdsArray():
    birds = animals[0]['bird']
    fishes = animals[1]['fish']
   
    print("birds are", birds)
    print("fishes are", fishes)

getBirdsArray()
```

Comment: Intention is to not use array indexing as numeric array index search, rather loop through and find key as this array will fit more values in future so it is better to not use numeric index search.

Answer (score -2):

```
animals = [
{
        "bird": ["crow"]
},
{
        "fish": ["salmon", "anchovy", "monkfish"]
}]


def get_birds_array():
    for animal in animals:
        for k, v in zip(animal.keys(), animal.values()):
            print(f"{k} are, {v}")


get_birds_array()
```

Comment: ``zip(animal.keys(), animal.values())`` is just ``animal.items()``, isn't it?

Comment: I did this so that he can understand what's going on.